# Loading gif not working in IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been searching and have found some similar questions about this problem but thing still doesn't work for me at all.

Here is my function :

```
function ajaxRequest(url, type, datatype, contenttype, data, displayLoadingImg){
 var result="";
 displayLoadingImg = (typeof displayLoadingImg === "undefined") ? 0 : displayLoadingImg;
 if(displayLoadingImg == 1){
    $("#loadingImgAging").css("display","block");
 }
 $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:type,
    dataType:datatype,
    contentType: contenttype,
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success:function(res){
        result = res;
        if(displayLoadingImg == 1){
            $("#loadingImgAging").css("display","none");
        }
    },
    error:function(res){
        result="";
    },
    async : false
 });
 return result;
}
```

How I call it :

```
setTimeout(ajaxRequest(url,"GET","json","application/json",0,1), 500);
```

I've tried using `beforeSend()` but it did not work neither.

**Note** : If I delete `async : false` or put it to `true`, I'll get error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked....` in my browser console.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you cannot do an ajax request with local files. There are ways to do this, but i prefer these two methods

- Create a simple server

I usually use python for creating a simple server. Type this in your terminal/console: "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9081" (or any port number you want to). Then, just open your localhost referring to your specified port.

- Open chrome in --allow-file-access-from-files mode

or create a batch file using this following code in Windows. Chrome must be restarted before the configuration takes place.

```
    start "chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --allow-file-        access-from-files
    exit
```

Comment: I am using windows, and using `--allow-file-access-from-files` mode, is still getting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error!

Comment: you must make sure all the chrome instances are closed before opening it in --allow-file-access-from-files mode

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making a AJAX call to another domain file for which you have to use JSONP as your dataType. Doing this you then dont have to make async = false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
before you do the ajax call set display to block, after the ajax call(success or error doesnt matter)  - just before you return - set display to none. You dont need displayLoadingImg and the code to handle it. Or do I miss ssomething?